# Windows encoding clarification

Tags: winapi, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I would like to translate a game, this game loads the strings from a text file.

The destination language uses non-ascii characters, so I naïvely saved my file in utf8, but it does not work as letters with diacritics are not shown correctly.

Studying better in the configuration file where the string text filename is stored, I found a CHARSET option that can assume any of those values:

ANSI_CHARSET DEFAULT_CHARSET SYMBOL_CHARSET MAC_CHARSET SHIFTJIS_CHARSET HANGEUL_CHARSET JOHAB_CHARSET GB2312_CHARSET CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET GREEK_CHARSET TURKISH_CHARSET VIETNAMESE_CHARSET HEBREW_CHARSET ARABIC_CHARSET BALTIC_CHARSET RUSSIAN_CHARSET THAI_CHARSET EASTEUROPE_CHARSET OEM_CHARSET

That as far as I understood are fairly standard values in WinAPIs and charset and character encoding are synonymous.

So my question is, is there a correspondence between this names and standard names like utf8 or iso-8859-2? If it is the case what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `EASTEUROPE_CHARSET`

[ISO 8859-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) is mostly equivalent to [Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250).  According to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915041.aspx) article, the 1250 code page is accessed using `EASTEUROPE_CHARSET`.

Note that you will need to save your text file in the 1250 code page as ISO 8859-2 is not exactly equivalent.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250):

> Windows-1250 is similar to ISO-8859-2 and has all the printable characters it has and more. However a few of them are rearranged (unlike Windows-1252, which keeps all printable characters from ISO-8859-1 in the same place). Most of the rearrangements seem to have been done to keep characters shared with Windows-1252 in the same place as in Windows-1252 but three of the characters moved (Ą,Ľ,ź) cannot be explained this way.

Comment: windows-1250 does not encode some characters I need. I need those specials: èéàìîòù ÈÉÀÌÎÒÙ. I tried writing a utf8 file with that text and I tried to convert it with: --iconv -c -f utf-8 -t windows-1250 DICRITICS-- It results that only é and î (and caps) are converted. However, if the codepage table you linked to relates to windows-X encodings I can try them out.

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni Those are available in `ANSI_CHARSET`, aka Windows 1252, aka "Western".

Answer (score 0):

The names are symbolic identifiers for Windows code pages, which are character encodings (= charsets) defined or adopted by Microsoft. Many of them are [registered at IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) with the prefix `windows-`. For example, `EASTEUROPE_CHARSET` stands for code page 1250, which has been registered as `windows-1250` and is often called Windows Latin 2.

UTF-8 is something different. You need special routines to read and write UTF-8 encoded data. UTF-8 or UTF-16 is generally the only sensible choice for character encoding when you want to be truly global (support different languages and writing systems). For a single specific language, some of the code pages might be more practical in some cases.

Comment: Do keep in mind that Microsoft does have a codepage for UTF-8: 65001.  There is no corresponding `XXX_CHARSET` for UTF-8, though.  The `XXX_CHARSET` values correspond to Ansi charsets.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the the standard encoding names (as registered by [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml)) using the table under the remarks section of this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915041.aspx) page.

Just find the Character set row and read the Code page number, the standard name is windows-[code page number].